# Adding columns to grid using Vaadin 8.0.7

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I want add column to grid, when i click to button ("backBtn"). Then i get the value from the textfield ("filterText"), and that will be the name of the new column. Who can help me? The code is from tutorial, but i need add the new feature here. Thanks ! You can find my code in attachment. Grid is in class "MyUI"

This is clas Customer

```
 package my.vaadin.app;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * A entity object, like in any other Java application. In a typical real world
 * application this could for example be a JPA entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Customer implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private Long id;

    private String firstName = "";

    private String datum = "";

    private String lastName = "";

    private LocalDate birthDate;

    private CustomerStatus status;

    private String email = "";

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of email
     *
     * @return the value of email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of email
     *
     * @param email
     *            new value of email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of status
     *
     * @return the value of status
     */
    public CustomerStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of status
     *
     * @param status
     *            new value of status
     */
    public void setStatus(CustomerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of birthDate
     *
     * @return the value of birthDate
     */
    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of birthDate
     *
     * @param birthDate
     *            new value of birthDate
     */
    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of lastName
     *
     * @return the value of lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of lastName
     *
     * @param lastName
     *            new value of lastName
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of firstName
     *
     * @return the value of firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of firstName
     *
     * @param firstName
     *            new value of firstName
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of firstName
     *
     * @param firstName
     *            new value of firstName
     */
    public void setDatum(String datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public boolean isPersisted() {
        return id != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.id == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj instanceof Customer && obj.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return this.id.equals(((Customer) obj).id);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 43 * hash + (id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Customer) super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

This is clas MyUI

```
    package my.vaadin.app;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.swing.text.TableView;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.event.ShortcutAction.KeyCode;
import com.vaadin.server.FontAwesome;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.ValueChangeMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.CssLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid.SelectionMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.PasswordField;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.components.grid.HeaderCell;
import com.vaadin.ui.components.grid.HeaderRow;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window 
 * (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be 
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    private CustomerService service = CustomerService.getInstance();
    private Grid<Customer> grid = new Grid<>(Customer.class);
    private TextField filterText = new TextField();
  //  private CustomerForm form = new CustomerForm(this);

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        Label tancore = new Label();


        filterText.setPlaceholder("Meno ...");
        //filterText.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateList());
        //filterText.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);

        Button clearFilterTextBtn = new Button(FontAwesome.TIMES);
        clearFilterTextBtn.setDescription("Clear the current name");
        clearFilterTextBtn.addClickListener(e -> filterText.clear());

        tancore.setCaption("TanCore s.r.o");
        CssLayout filtering = new CssLayout();
        filtering.addComponents(filterText, clearFilterTextBtn);
        filtering.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);

        Button addCustomerBtn = new Button("Pridaj zamestnanca");
        Button downloadXlsBtn = new Button("Stiahnuť ako .xls");
        Button loginBtn = new Button("Prihlásiť sa");
      //  Button addEmplBtn = new Button("Pridaj");
        Button backBtn = new Button("Vlož");
       downloadXlsBtn.setVisible(false);
        TextField name = new TextField();
        PasswordField pass = new PasswordField();

     //   addEmplBtn.setVisible(false);
        addCustomerBtn.setVisible(false);   
        backBtn.setVisible(false);
        filtering.setVisible(false);
        clearFilterTextBtn.setVisible(false);
        filterText.setVisible(false);

        addCustomerBtn.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
        //.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
        addCustomerBtn.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER);

        backBtn.addClickListener(e -> {

            //Here i want include the new data after click on the button

            //grid.addColumn(filterText.getValue()); -> That it's not good, because after click the Java will Warning you


            addCustomerBtn.setVisible(true);
            backBtn.setVisible(false);
            filtering.setVisible(false);
            clearFilterTextBtn.setVisible(false);
            filterText.setVisible(false);


        });

        addCustomerBtn.addClickListener(e -> {
            addCustomerBtn.setVisible(false);
            filtering.setVisible(true);
            backBtn.setVisible(true);
            clearFilterTextBtn.setVisible(true);
            filterText.setVisible(true);
            //addEmplBtn.setEnabled(true);

        });


        loginBtn.addClickListener(e -> {


            if(name.getValue().equals("admin"))
            {
                if(pass.getValue().equals("admin"))
        {
                name.setVisible(false);
                pass.setVisible(false);
                loginBtn.setVisible(false);
                addCustomerBtn.setVisible(true);
                  downloadXlsBtn.setVisible(true);
        }
            }

        });


        pass.setPlaceholder("Heslo ...");
        name.setPlaceholder("Meno ...");
        HorizontalLayout toolbar = new HorizontalLayout(name, pass, loginBtn,filtering, addCustomerBtn,backBtn,downloadXlsBtn);



       // grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
        grid.setColumns("datum", "lastName","email","status");



       // grid.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);

        /*HeaderRow extraHeader = grid.prependHeaderRow();
        HeaderCell joinedCell = extraHeader.join("datum", "lastName");
        joinedCell.setText("Joined cell");*/

       HorizontalLayout main = new HorizontalLayout(grid);
       main.setSizeFull();
       grid.setSizeFull();
      //  main.setExpandRatio(grid, 1);

        grid.getColumn("datum").setWidth(100);
       // grid.getColumn("datum").set
      //  grid.getColumn("datum").set
        grid.getColumn("datum").setCaption("Dátum");
        grid.getColumn("lastName").setCaption("Adam");

        layout.addComponents(toolbar, main);

        // fetch list of Customers from service and assign it to Grid
        updateList();

        setContent(layout);




     //   form.setVisible(false);

        grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            //if (event.getValue() == null) {
              //  form.setVisible(false);
            //} else {
              //  form.setCustomer(event.getValue());
            //}
        });
    }

    public void updateList() {
        List<Customer> customers = service.findAll(filterText.getValue());
        grid.setItems(customers);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

This is clas CustomerForm.java

```
package my.vaadin.app;

import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.event.ShortcutAction.KeyCode;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.DateField;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.NativeSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;

public class CustomerForm extends FormLayout {

    private TextField firstName = new TextField("First name");
    private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last name");
    private TextField email = new TextField("Email");
    private NativeSelect<CustomerStatus> status = new NativeSelect<>("Status");
    private DateField birthdate = new DateField("Birthday");
    private Button save = new Button("Save");
    private Button delete = new Button("Delete");

    private CustomerService service = CustomerService.getInstance();
    private Customer customer;
    private MyUI myUI;
    private Binder<Customer> binder = new Binder<>(Customer.class);

    public CustomerForm(MyUI myUI) {
        this.myUI = myUI;

        setSizeUndefined();
        HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout(save, delete);
        addComponents(firstName, lastName, email, status, birthdate, buttons);

        status.setItems(CustomerStatus.values());
        save.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
        save.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER);

        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

        save.addClickListener(e -> this.save());
        delete.addClickListener(e -> this.delete());
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        binder.setBean(customer);

        // Show delete button for only customers already in the database
        delete.setVisible(customer.isPersisted());
        setVisible(true);
        firstName.selectAll();
    }

    private void delete() {
        service.delete(customer);
        myUI.updateList();
        setVisible(false);
    }

    private void save() {
        service.save(customer);
        myUI.updateList();
        setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

This is clas CustomerService.java

```
package my.vaadin.app;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * An in memory dummy "database" for the example purposes. In a typical Java app
 * this class would be replaced by e.g. EJB or a Spring based service class.
 * <p>
 * In demos/tutorials/examples, get a reference to this service class with
 * {@link CustomerService#getInstance()}.
 */
public class CustomerService {

    private static CustomerService instance;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomerService.class.getName());

    private final HashMap<Long, Customer> contacts = new HashMap<>();
    private long nextId = 0;

    private CustomerService() {
    }

    /**
     * @return a reference to an example facade for Customer objects.
     */
    public static CustomerService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CustomerService();
            instance.ensureTestData();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return all available Customer objects.
     */
    public synchronized List<Customer> findAll() {
        return findAll(null);
    }

    /**
     * Finds all Customer's that match given filter.
     *
     * @param stringFilter
     *            filter that returned objects should match or null/empty string
     *            if all objects should be returned.
     * @return list a Customer objects
     */
    public synchronized List<Customer> findAll(String stringFilter) {
        ArrayList<Customer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Customer contact : contacts.values()) {
            try {
                boolean passesFilter = (stringFilter == null || stringFilter.isEmpty())
                        || contact.toString().toLowerCase().contains(stringFilter.toLowerCase());
                if (passesFilter) {
                    arrayList.add(contact.clone());
                }
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CustomerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Customer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
                return (int) (o2.getId() - o1.getId());
            }
        });
        return arrayList;
    }

    /**
     * Finds all Customer's that match given filter and limits the resultset.
     *
     * @param stringFilter
     *            filter that returned objects should match or null/empty string
     *            if all objects should be returned.
     * @param start
     *            the index of first result
     * @param maxresults
     *            maximum result count
     * @return list a Customer objects
     */
    public synchronized List<Customer> findAll(String stringFilter, int start, int maxresults) {
        ArrayList<Customer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Customer contact : contacts.values()) {
            try {
                boolean passesFilter = (stringFilter == null || stringFilter.isEmpty())
                        || contact.toString().toLowerCase().contains(stringFilter.toLowerCase());
                if (passesFilter) {
                    arrayList.add(contact.clone());
                }
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CustomerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Customer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
                return (int) (o2.getId() - o1.getId());
            }
        });
        int end = start + maxresults;
        if (end > arrayList.size()) {
            end = arrayList.size();
        }
        return arrayList.subList(start, end);
    }

    /**
     * @return the amount of all customers in the system
     */
    public synchronized long count() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a customer from a system
     *
     * @param value
     *            the Customer to be deleted
     */
    public synchronized void delete(Customer value) {
        contacts.remove(value.getId());
    }

    /**
     * Persists or updates customer in the system. Also assigns an identifier
     * for new Customer instances.
     *
     * @param entry
     */
    public synchronized void save(Customer entry) {
        if (entry == null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Customer is null. Are you sure you have connected your form to the application as described in tutorial chapter 7?");
            return;
        }
        if (entry.getId() == null) {
            entry.setId(nextId++);
        }
        try {
            entry = (Customer) entry.clone();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        contacts.put(entry.getId(), entry);
    }

    /**
     * Sample data generation
     */
    public void ensureTestData() {
        if (findAll().isEmpty()) {


            for (int i = 31; i > 0; i--) {

                Customer c = new Customer();
                c.setDatum(i+".7");
                save(c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

I want have this in my WebApp

[image]

This is actualy my WebApp

[image]

Comment: You're getting an exception because you've bound the grid to `Customer`, and `grid.addColumn(filterText.getValue())` will look for a property in your `Customer` with the same name as what you typed in that "filter box", and it won't find it. You can use the [other variants of the `addColumn` method](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.7/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#addColumn-com.vaadin.data.ValueProvider-): eg: `grid.addColumn(Customer::getId).setCaption("New ID column")`.

Comment: @Morfic when i use your method, i don't see any change in my grid (new column). But don't see any error too. Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: @Morfic I have the new Column, but with data from Customer ID :( -> Check the new picture in my post. But i need include new data to the new column

Comment: That was an example to illustrate how you can add the column, but you can supply your own value provider. Where do you get the data for the new column from?

Comment: @Morfic I want get data from ArrayList (List). Please help me with that, how i can set the data. Check the new post -> My last 2 class - CustomerForm and CustomerService. I want add the data to the specific columns

Comment: @Morfic Please Morfic, how i can set the data to the table, when i want adding data to the specific columns and rows ? And don't want have the old data that are specific for the Id from the Customer. I want have there my own data

Comment: People do take brakes once in a while you know, especially during the weekend, and sometimes there are timezone differences, so it may take a while before you get a response... Nonetheless, it's not clear what data you want to put in your new column, you just mention how to set its caption. You say you want to add data from `ArrayList` but you don't say how you get it and what it contains. Where do those numbers in the screen shot come from?. Please **try to describe your scenario** so we can figure out what goes where.