# Adding the data to the specific columns and rows using Vaadin 7.8.4 (Java)

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, cell

How I can include the data to the grid at the specific row and column? When i want add the data e.g to the blue cell? Thank you! [image]

Comment: is it jTable or a Vaddin component?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK It is Grid -> Vaadin component.

Comment: In vaadin you have a Container as the datasource of a grid. So add your data at the correct place in your datasource and trigger a data changed or itemchanged event as required to get the new data

Comment: What data? How do you want to add it, from the backend? From the GUI by double clicking the cell? Please describe your scenario. **P.S.** is this related to [Adding columns to grid using Vaadin 8.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220261/adding-columns-to-grid-using-vaadin-8-0-7)?

Comment: @Morfic I want to programmatically (using code) display some data at any particular cell. By the click on the cell but i want loading data to the cells from database too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vaadin -> Grid, all rows are identified by an unique ID, which depends on which kind of container you used to store that data.

Let's have an example on `IndexedContainer`. In this container, you can specify the row ID when you do `addItem([Object itemId])`. This id is what you are gonna use to write in a particular cell. To write in a particular column, you can obtain an `itemProperty` which is where that cell value is stored. Using that `IndexedContainer` example, code will look like this:

```
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
//Add container properties like "name"
//container.addContainerProperty("name", String.class,"");
//From IndexedContainer docs: addContainerProperty(Object propertyId, Class type, Object defaultValue)
container.addItem(1);
Item item = container.getItem(1);
item.getItemProperty("name").setValue(someValue);
```

It will allow you to write on cells.
If instead an Indexed, you are using a `BeanItemContainer`, per example, the object inserted will be used as data and ID.

EDIT: To set any container as the data source of a grid, write `grid.setContainerDataSource(containerName);`

Comment: How i can add the container to the my grid ?

Comment: IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer(); grid.addColumn("NewColumn",String.class);  grid.removeAllColumns();
        grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
        
        container.addItem(1);
        Item item = container.getItem(1);
        item.getItemProperty("name").setValue("Hello");

I get the error with null pointer exception

Comment: In the code theres a comment saying "add container properties like name". It is done writing `container.addContainerProperty("name", String.class, "");` see IndexedContainer docs to see more details.

Comment: @Ady96 Please, accept the answer if it solved the problem.