# Using Vaadin 7.4.9 - How to delete data from the grid

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I need to delete data from the grid (container) and then i need refresh the rows. How I can do it?

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
container.addContainerProperty("firstNumber", Integer.class, 0);
container.addContainerProperty("secondNumber", Integer.class, 0);

container.addItem(1);

Item item = container.getItem(1);
int firstNumber = item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").setValue("1");

item = container.getItem(1);
int secondNumber = item.getItemProperty("secondNumber").setValue("2");
```

Now I try to change cell only without delete item. My code is

```
container.addValueChangeListener(e -> {

         Item item = container.getItem(35);
         item.getItemProperty("Person5").setValue("SS");

         grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
         grid.clearSortOrder();
         grid.refreshAllRows();

     });
```

but the I have error too ... :(

[image]

---

Info for Morfic:

I need change data displayed in the grid cell. So ... I have e.g 3 rows with propertyIds firstNumber and secondNumber, the 4th row represent the sum of the rows. So, I have some data whitch I get from the database. And I need include some data manually "from keyboard" to the grid ...

Imagine the situation:

firstNumber have data in grid 1,null,2 - the sum in the 4th cell is 3. I want add or change data in the cell. Now I add at the second position number 5. In grid I have now numbers: 1,5 and 2. I want in no time have the sum 8 in the 4th cell. This is my big problem.

I tried add ValueChangeListener to the grid.

```
     container.addValueChangeListener(e -> {

     int sum = 0;

     for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
     {
       Item item = container.getItem(i);
       sum += (Integer) item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").getValue();
     }

       item = container.getItem(4);
       item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").setValue(sum);

       grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
       grid.clearSortOrder();
       grid.refreshAllRows();

 });
```

So I get the error:

```
sep 15, 2017 4:16:21 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
com.vaadin.data.Buffered$SourceException
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:546)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:468)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractTextField.changeVariables(AbstractTextField.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:616)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:463)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:406)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:366)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty.setValue(IndexedContainer.java:848)
    at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.lambda$11(MyUI.java:3931)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.firePropertyValueChange(IndexedContainer.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.access$1000(IndexedContainer.java:63)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty.setValue(IndexedContainer.java:867)
    at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.lambda$11(MyUI.java:3931)
```

My question is, that i can have the sum of the rows in the last row. Not in the new column :) Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `delete data`. Are you trying to remove rows? Are you trying to clear the value displayed in a cell? Something else? Also please add the full stacktrace as text instead of a screenshot which does not contain the entire stack, and keep in mind that providing a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your issue, will greatly increase your chances for a solution.

Comment: @Morfic check post now

Comment: @Morfic where are you ?

Comment: I'm on vacation, somewhere in the mountains, enjoying the weekend and a cold beer, thanks for asking. And you?

Comment: :D At home. Tomorrow start school. So sad :/ :D And how about the problem in my program ?

Comment: @Morfic please help me with this problem. I really need your help.

Comment: Sorry to be this blunt, but you didn't seem to understand [the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220261/adding-columns-to-grid-using-vaadin-8-0-7#comment77512938_45220261), so I'll say it once more: SO is not a coder renting service and the community members help others of their own volition, when they have the time and feel like it, after all, everybody has their own life, problems, hobbies, etc to attend to. Next time you **expect** someone to answer when you want/need them to, please do take a minute to also consider these aspects, because we're not your personal servants...

Comment: Yes, I know that, sorry man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError` problem is because you're changing values inside a `ValueChangeListener`, which generates other events, and you end up in an endless loop, as **@Manuel Kollegger** was trying to point out, so a different approach is required.

The simplest idea which came to mind, is to have a generated column, for which you calculate the value based on the other 2. However, as per the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.overview.table), there's no direct way in Vaadin 7 to define a generated column, so you have to wrap your container with a `GeneratedPropertyContainer`:

> Grid has no generated columns. Instead, the container data source can be wrapped around a `GeneratedPropertyContainer`.

Also, you may wish to make the generate property read-only, to prevent the user from manually editing it.

The example below, based on your description, shows how this is done. Please note that for the sake of brevity, it's not entirely fool-proof (nulls, invalid values, etc), but it should get you started:

```
import com.vaadin.data.Item;
import com.vaadin.data.util.GeneratedPropertyContainer;
import com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer;
import com.vaadin.data.util.PropertyValueGenerator;
import com.vaadin.ui.Grid;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.util.Random;

public class GridWithCalculatedColumn extends VerticalLayout {

    public GridWithCalculatedColumn() {
        // indexed container allowing the definition of custom properties
        IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
        container.addContainerProperty("firstNumber", Integer.class, 0);
        container.addContainerProperty("secondNumber", Integer.class, 0);

        // generated property container allowing the definition of generated properties
        GeneratedPropertyContainer wrappingContainer = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(container);
        wrappingContainer.addGeneratedProperty("sum", new PropertyValueGenerator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer getValue(Item item, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
                // sum the other 2 columns
                // NOTE: for the sake of simplicity this does not handle invalid values such as "null"
                return (Integer) item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").getValue() + (Integer) item.getItemProperty("secondNumber").getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public Class<Integer> getType() {
                return Integer.class;
            }
        });

        // add some dummy data
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Item item = wrappingContainer.addItem(i);
            item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").setValue(random.nextInt(10));
            item.getItemProperty("secondNumber").setValue(random.nextInt(10));
        }


        // basic grid setup
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.setContainerDataSource(wrappingContainer);
        grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
        // disable editing of the "calculated value"
        grid.getColumn("sum").setEditable(false);
        addComponent(grid);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: vaadin 7 - grid generated property]

Comment: And sorry for asking but, is the same when i want changing values in the row, not in the column ? What is the procedure?

Comment: @Ady96 not sure what you mean by `changing values in the row, not int the column`? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes sure :) I add the new picture to my post. Thank you very much Mr. Morfic :)

Comment: @Ady96 that's stuff for a new question, try to keep them clean and separate, so others having similar issues ca easily figure out if that's the case and quickly identify the fix. I'll try to think about it tomorrow, now it's bed time, but meanwhile, it may be worth checking if you can do it with grid footer.

Comment: Yes man, i thinking about grid footer, but i need calculate numbers in few rows... And i don't want have 10 footer rows ...

Answer (score 0):

Using Vaadin 7.4.9 is very tedious when it comes to Grids.

Removing items has to be done using `container.removeItem(item)`.

Additionally refreshing a Grid is easy in Vaadin 7.7 (method addition of `refreshAll` and `refreshRow()`) and especially easy in Vaadin 8 (using events and a Dataprovider).

In Vaadin 7 you will have to hack it a bit by calling `clearSortOrder` which automatically redraws the grid.

The following code is used when you update the UI from another Thread (i.e. not in a ValueChangeListener) however you need to enable the Vaadin-Push Addon which is a separate dependency.

```
getUI.access(() -> {
        List<SortOrder> sortOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        grid.getSortOrder().forEach(sortOrder -> sortOrders.add(sortOrder));
        grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
        grid.clearSortOrder();
        grid.setSortOrder(sortOrders);

        getUI().push();
    });
```

Edit: If you do the deletion with a buttonClick or ValueChangeEvent of a combobox you can simply do:

```
component.addValueChangeListener(e -> {

         Item item = container.getItem(35);
         container.removeItem(item);    

         container.addItem(35);

         item.getItemProperty("Person5").setValue("SS");

         grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
         grid.clearSortOrder();
         grid.refreshAllRows();

     });
```

However be careful, your implementation has a ValueChangeListener on the container which calls `container.removeItem(35)` this will result in another trigger another ValueChanged-Event which will try to remove item number 35 again. You have to use another component for the ValueChangeListener otherwise you run into an endless cycle

Comment: What does it mean getUI and "sortorder" ? ... I have about 35 rows, and my code is like :    Item item = container.getItem(35);
      container.removeItem(item); 
    
     
         grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
         grid.clearSortOrder();
         grid.refreshAllRows();
      
         container.addItem(item);
       
      item.getItemProperty("firstNumber").setValue("SSSS");. This is wrong, I have error with this ...

Comment: Are you doing this in a `getUI.access` block? (This is done to avoid concurrency issues).
Whats the exact error you are having?

Comment: Check my post now. I need something, that will be okey :/

Comment: how can I solve it? What will be another component ?

Comment: As I have written in my answer the problem is that you trigger a `ValueChangedEvent` in your `ValueChangedListener`

You CANNOT have `item.getItemProperty("Person5").setValue("SS");`
and also no `container.removeItem()` within your ValueChangedListener

Comment: I don't remove the container item now, only change the Value. But how i can solve the problem. What should I do? How I can update my code, or can you write the correct code here? Thanks

Comment: you have to move `item.getItemProperty("Person5").setValue("SS");` outside of the Listener -> you have to do it on some other event (i.e. a buttonclick)

Comment: And what will be in the container.addValueChangeListener?

Comment: in there you have `grid.recalculateColumnWidths();
         grid.clearSortOrder();
         grid.refreshAllRows();` that way the grid is drawn again as soon as the container changes

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand. I need get the change (update grid) after insert the new data in the grid. I don't want click on the button and then will be data insert into the grid. I need insert the value into the cell and in this same time in the other cells will be new data