# Set results from math operations into Vaadin Grid in real time (Manually inserting), Using Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin

The main thing of my problem is, that I want inserting data into my grid from keyboard. Some data are loaded from the database, and user can change (can change the loaded data too) or insert the new data into grid (manually). Then I want have see the results from the columns in last rows (Check the results in my picture) - Results means the number in rows where in the first column is data like - sum, average, min, max ...

[image]

So, when I click on the third row, into column e.g Person 3, and when I will change the value from 5 to 6 and **in this time** the sum will be 16, max will be 6, min 1 and average will be 3.2

My code of Grid is:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();

IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);

container.addContainerProperty("September", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person1", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person2", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person3", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person4", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person5", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person6", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person7", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Person8", String.class, null);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     container.addItem(i);

Item item = container.getItem(1);

item.getItemProperty("September").setValue("1.9.2017 Piatok");

item = container.getItem(2);
item.getItemProperty("September").setValue("2.9.2017 Sobota");

....
```

I tried to add the addValueChangeListener to the grid (container)

```
container.addValueChangeListener(e -> {

       int sum = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
         Item item = container.getItem(i);
         sum += (Integer) item.getItemProperty("Person3").getValue();
       }

         item = container.getItem(6);
         item.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(sum);

     });
```

But I get the error message:

```
sep 15, 2017 4:16:21 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
com.vaadin.data.Buffered$SourceException
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:546)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:468)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractTextField.changeVariables(AbstractTextField.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:616)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:463)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:406)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:366)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty.setValue(IndexedContainer.java:848)
    at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.lambda$11(MyUI.java:3931)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.firePropertyValueChange(IndexedContainer.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.access$1000(IndexedContainer.java:63)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer$IndexedContainerProperty.setValue(IndexedContainer.java:867)
    at my.vaadin.app.MyUI.lambda$11(MyUI.java:3931)
```

Problem is when I try to change 2 and more cells ...

```
 container.addValueChangeListener(e -> {


                Item item = container.getItem(6);

                 if(!e.getProperty().equals(item.getItemProperty("Person3")))
                        item.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(54 + "");

                 if(!e.getProperty().equals(item.getItemProperty("Person4")))
                    item.getItemProperty("Person4").setValue(65 + "");

          });
```

How I can Fix it ?

[image]

This is the problem, I don't want have this footer always visible at the grid. I want see the footers only when I come to the end of the grid. Do you understand that?

Comment: You get that error because you change the field values in a value change listener, so other change events are generated, so the listener is triggered indefinitely. I guess the simplest way is to do the same, but using 5 footer rows. This also prevents the user from manually editing these _calculated_ values.

Comment: @Morfic but this footer rows are visible always when i scrolling the grid... And i don't want that ... Or?

Comment: @Morfic if I have to choose this way, i need something that can place the footer on the one position, the best will be, when the footer will be at the bottom of the grid. And then you can scrolling inside the grid, and the footer will stay at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The footer is always at the bottom, just as the header is always at the top. What do you expect to happen when you scroll?

Comment: @Morfic check my Gif and coment in post :)

Comment: You could also, instead using an *always-visible* footer, add rows at the end of your container. There are two methods that may help you: [IndexedContainer#addItemAfter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html#addItemAfter-java.lang.Object-) and [IndexedContainer#addItemAt](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html#addItemAt-int-)

Comment: @Shirkam what you mean ? I don't understand your idea.

Comment: You want some footer row that is only displayed when you are at bottom of the grid. That is not currently possible, using just a normal footer, cause they are always visible. To simulate that pseudo footer, you can add a/some last "footer-row" in your container, that will hold all that statistic info. If you want to add more "normal-rows" to the container, you must use those `addItemAt` methods, so your last(s) row(s) always hold that statistical data.

Comment: @Shirkam but when I insert the new row(s) at the end of the grid, it will be the same container, and it will cause the same problem, or ? Can you show me example of your idea? Some code that you insert in my examples. And when the your answer will be correct I can accept it in my post :)

Comment: @Shirkam, because when i add the new row into the same container, it cause the same problem

Comment: @Morfic Do you have the same idea? Or what is yours?

Comment: If you don't want to use the footer, I'm thinking it may be possible to to the calculation when the editor changes are committed, `grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(...)` instead of the `ValueChangeListener`, but I'll have to try it first. Or you could do it in the mean-time. Also, you probably If need to figure out a way to prevent editing the _calculated_ rows.

Comment: @Morfic No I only need insert the new data into grid (manually). Then I want have see the results from the columns in last rows :) Like in picture. But can you add your example with my code here please Morfic ? Where I could insert your code "grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(...)" ? Instead       if(!e.getProperty().equals(item.getItemProperty("Person3"))) ? And what will be in the commit handler (instead parentheses) ?

Comment: Like i said, replace the value change listener with the commit handler, so the logic of updating the results goes in the commit handler now (maybe with minor changes). The commit handler is called when the editor changes are saved, so you should not have the stack overflow error any longer. I'm on the road right now so i can't test to see if it works as expected, but you can try in the meantime if you're at the PC.

Comment: @Morfic I tried to include your idea into my code, I found something with the commitHandler at the page https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/9683271/13162177 but I can't understand It. And I do not know exactly what you wanted to do with it (your idea). I will be very happy when you will can to look at this problem, when you will get back from your journey.

Comment: Hello @Morfic. Have you looked at it? I don't know what I must doing. Please, can you help me? Of Course only if you are not on the road. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by now you've figured out why you're getting a SOE by using a `ValueChangeListener` to update the *sum row*, you can overcome this problem with a similar approach by using an editor [`CommitHandler`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.9/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroup.CommitHandler.html), so when the editor changes are saved, the *sum row* is updated. For the sake of brevity the sample below only calculates the sum, but you can apply similar logic for the rest of your operations:

```
public class GridWithCalculatedRow extends VerticalLayout {

    public GridWithCalculatedRow() {
        // indexed container allowing the definition of custom properties
        IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
        container.addContainerProperty("September", String.class, null);
        container.addContainerProperty("Person1", Integer.class, 0);
        container.addContainerProperty("Person2", Integer.class, 0);
        container.addContainerProperty("Person3", Integer.class, 0);


        // add some dummy data
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Item item = container.addItem(i);
            item.getItemProperty("September").setValue(String.valueOf(i));
            item.getItemProperty("Person1").setValue(random.nextInt(10));
            item.getItemProperty("Person2").setValue(random.nextInt(10));
            item.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(random.nextInt(10));
        }

        Item sumItem = container.addItem(6);
        sumItem.getItemProperty("September").setValue("Sum");

        // basic grid setup
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
        grid.getColumn("September").setEditable(false);
        addComponent(grid);

        // initial sum
        updateSum(container, sumItem);

        // disable editing of sum item
        grid.addItemClickListener(event -> {
            if (event.getItemId().equals(6)) {
                grid.setEditorEnabled(false);
            } else {
                grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
            }
        });


        // editor commit handler to update the sum
        grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new FieldGroup.CommitHandler() {
            @Override
            public void preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws FieldGroup.CommitException {
                // nothing to do here for now
            }

            @Override
            public void postCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws FieldGroup.CommitException {
                updateSum(container, sumItem);
            }
        });

    }

    // recalculate all sums and update the sum item
    private void updateSum(IndexedContainer container, Item sumItem) {
        Integer person1Sum = 0;
        Integer person2Sum = 0;
        Integer person3Sum = 0;

        // calculate sums
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Item item = container.getItem(i);
            person1Sum += (Integer) item.getItemProperty("Person1").getValue();
            person2Sum += (Integer) item.getItemProperty("Person2").getValue();
            person3Sum += (Integer) item.getItemProperty("Person3").getValue();

        }

        // update grid item
        sumItem.getItemProperty("Person1").setValue(person1Sum);
        sumItem.getItemProperty("Person2").setValue(person2Sum);
        sumItem.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(person3Sum);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: vaadin-grid-with-calculated-row]

Comment: Thank you ! :) And I have last question. Can I do this without buffered editor mode ?

Comment: @Ady96 I haven't used in in un-buffered mode so far. At first glance it behaves differently and the commit handler is not triggered, so I can't really say. It needs more investigation

Comment: SOE means `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 3):

This is already answered in [Using Vaadin 7.4.9 - How to delete data from the grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078096/using-vaadin-7-4-9-how-to-delete-data-from-the-grid)
The cause is the same, you are calling `container.setValue` within the `container.addValueChangeListener` resulting in an endless loop.

You can NOT CALL `item.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(sum);` within the listener.

You have to check if the item you are currently setting is not already set the last time you visited your loop.
Imagine the following:

```
int otherValue = 10;

public setValue(int newValue) {
  int sum = newValue + otherValue; //this is your sum
  setValue(sum);    //of course this causes a StackOverFlowError
}
```

Here is a solution that could work for your project:

```
if(!e.getProperty().equals(item.getItemProperty("Person3"))
    item.getItemProperty("Person3").setValue(sum);
```

Comment: That is right, but i need get data from the all properties not only one :)

Comment: The easiest way for you would be to split the grid into an inputgrid and a resultgrid.

Comment: Or `THE BAD SOLUTION` have a boolean that tells you when you are doing an edit within the `ValueChangeListener`. This is discouraged, of course, but "useful".

Comment: Check my edited post ... Because, for one property it is good but problem is when i want calculate the results for more than 1 property ...